# Access value with key in bimap

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bimap

I am trying to get a value accessed by its key. I have a minimal example that I tried so far, and works fine only for left side access.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>

namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;
typedef boost::bimap<bimaps::set_of<unsigned long int>,
        bimaps::multiset_of<std::pair<unsigned long int, unsigned long int> > > bimap_reference;
typedef bimap_reference::value_type position;
bimap_reference numbers;

int main()
{
    numbers.insert(position(123456, std::make_pair(100000,50000)));
    numbers.insert(position(234567, std::make_pair(200000,80000)));
    numbers.insert(position(345678, std::make_pair(300000,10000)));
    numbers.insert(position(456789 ,std::make_pair(100000,60000)));


    auto it = numbers.left.at(123456);
    std::cout<<"numbers:"<<it.first<<"<->"<<it.second<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I tried to look from the right by using a paired key to access a value, and as a trail I tried the following.

```
auto itt = numbers.right.at({100000,50000});
auto itt = numbers.right.at(std::make_pair(100000,50000));
std::cout<<"from right: "<<itt.first<<std::endl;
```

> >
>   error: ‘boost::bimaps::bimap, boost::bimaps::multiset_of > >::right_map {aka class boost::bimaps::views::multimap_view, boost::bimaps::multiset_of >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> >}’ has no member named ‘at’
>        auto itt = numbers.right.at({100000,50000});

The above lines are not working. I also would like to know if it is possible to get access by using only one element of paired key something like

```
auto itt = numbers.right.at({50000});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation already contains all what you need to diagnose the problem.

First of all, note that the *type* of your right view is `multiset_of`.
As you can see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/discovering_the_bimap_framework.html), `multiset_of`'s equivalent container is [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) and the latter has not the member function `at`.
Because of that, you cannot invoke `at` on a `multiset_of`, that is what you get when accessing the right view of the map through `.right`.
The error is also pretty clear indeed.

You can use `find` to get out an iterator to the object you are looking for:

```
auto itt = numbers.right.find(std::make_pair(100000,50000));
std::cout<<"from right: "<<itt->first.first <<std::endl;
```

Well, checking it against `.end()` would probably be a good idea.

And no, you cannot search with half a key as a parameter. If you want to do things like that you should rather use something like a map where the keys are the first elements of your pairs and the values are lists of those pairs or some other data structure that is well suited for your real problem.
Definitely (almost) unfeasible with a `bimap`, it doesn't worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I wanted to use `.at()` to have fast access. Using .`find()` may not be so fast because `bimap` is too large. And if I can't search with half parameter, It is doubling the work, because my job is done with half search. Could you please suggest the data structures which have such type of functionality, indeed fast.

Comment: Added more details to the answer. My two cents: if you want to go with a `multiset_of`, use `find` unless you can demonstrate that performance are bad for you. That being said, you cannot use `at` with a `multiset_of`, it doesn't have that member function. It's not a matter of preferences.